# limit a voronoi diagram within country border in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, voronoi

I'm trying to generate a voronoi diagram on a map. What I'm trying to do accomplish is to limit the voronooi diagram within the border of the map, but I cannot figure it out how to do that.

Here is part of the code I have for now. Can someone provide at least some thoughts so that I can try? I'm not sure where to start. I'm new to d3.js.

Thank you so much!

```
  var vertices = dhs.map(function(d) { return [+d.lon, +d.lat]; });
  var median = dhs.map(function(d) { return +d.dhsMedian; });
  var max = d3.max(median, function(d) { return d; });
  var min = d3.min(median, function(d) { return d; });
  console.log(max);
  console.log(min);

  var medianScale = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([min, max])
                      .range([0, 90]);
  var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
      .clipExtent([0, 0], [width, height]);

  var voronoied_vertices = voronoi(vertices);

  var input = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    input.push(
        {
          "vertice":voronoied_vertices[i],
          "median":medianScale(median[i])
        }
      )
  };

  layer4.selectAll("path")
     .data(input)
     .enter().append("svg:path")
     .classed("voronoi", true)
     .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d["vertice"].map(function(d) { return projection(d); }).join("L") + "Z"; })
     .attr("id", function(d) {
      console.log(d['median']);
        if ( 0 <= d["median"] && d["median"] < 10) { return "color1"; }
        else if (10<= d["median"] && d["median"] <20) { return "color2"; }
        else if (20<= d["median"] && d["median"] <30) { return "color3"; }
        else if (30<= d["median"] && d["median"] <40) { return "color4"; }
        else if (40<= d["median"] && d["median"] <50) { return "color5"; }
        else if (50<= d["median"] && d["median"] <60) { return "color6"; }
        else if (60<= d["median"] && d["median"] <70) { return "color7"; }
        else if (70<= d["median"] && d["median"] <80) { return "color8"; }
        else { return "color9"; }

     });

  layer1.selectAll(".district")
      .data(topojson.feature(rwanda, rwanda.objects.district).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "district")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return "district" + d.id; })
      .attr("d", path);
```

Comment: You may find this example hepful: http://blockbuilder.org/blehman/220714d6a5af0c19aeaad3682c9c47a6

Answer (score 0):

If you have all voronoi and country shape find the edges from the voronoi diagram outside the shape and find the intersection with the country edge. You can try the midpoint of the country edge.

Comment: Not sure how exactly I can approach this. My puzzle is how I can find the edges from the voronoi diagram outside the country border. Can you explain a little more? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on the following example:

https://chriszetter.com/voronoi-map/examples/uk-supermarkets/#

Here, Leaflet and D3.js are used in combination.

If you go into the [code](https://chriszetter.com/voronoi-map/lib/voronoi_map.js), you'll find at row 92ff:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds(),
    ...
    ...
    ...
    drawLimit = bounds.pad(0.4);

filteredPoints = pointsFilteredToSelectedTypes().filter(function(d) {
  var latlng = new L.LatLng(d.latitude, d.longitude);

  if (!drawLimit.contains(latlng)) { return false };
  ...
```

Here you can apply the respective boundaries for your window (e.g.).

Hope this helps.